# Laravel uses two php.ini file

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have installed Laravel project on Xampp folder and it uses `php.ini` for phpMyAdmin with this path - `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. But when I would like to create the facebook login, I have to put `cacert.pem` and write the absolute path in `php.ini` file outside Xampp folder, which is `C:\php\php.ini`. If I use `php.ini` in Xampp folder, it is not working.

I also checked `phpinfo()` on Xampp dashboard and found that Loaded Configuration File is `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. But when I check `phpinfo()` via the blade file, I found that Loaded Configuration Files in `C:\php\php.ini`.

So, my question is how can I change `php.ini` path in Laravel? And why it 's not use Xampp'php.ini file.

Comment: Check your site configuration for Laravel and compare it with the default one. PHP is either loaded via a module or using fpm via the webserver fcgi module. Check if both these site configurations are consistent

Comment: Are you running laravel through php artisan serve?

Comment: @ZenelRrushi yes

Comment: then the problem is that php from command line and php from xamp have different configuration files because they are supposed to be in that way and there are configurations that make sense to be in a certain way in a webserver (xampp) and cli.
ES. in cli generally there is not timeout meanwhile in a webserver there is. Check my answer on how you can configure laravel to run with xampp so you can have same php.ini file as config

Answer (score 0):

PHP from **XAMPP** and PHP from **CLI** have different configuration files.
In your case php in **XAMPP** has `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` as configuration meanwhile PHP from Command Line has path `C:\php\php.ini`

If you need to have them same path you would suggest setting up a Virtual Host on XAMPP that will run your app and the php.ini file would be the one in path `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

To setup a xampp virtual host you can follow [this guide](https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server/).

Comment: Sorry, I am busy. I will reply you soon.

Comment: I am still confused. Because if I tested with WordPress on Xampp, and I put phpinfo() in homepage. It shows Loaded Configuration File is C:\xampp\php\php.ini file.

Comment: yes because you are not running wordpress with php from command line. You are running it from xampp
in laravel you either put the folder there and open it http://localhost/nameoflaravel but you need to be careful as you need also to configure base url of laravel as for routing it will not work very good or create a virtualhost like in the link in answer

Comment: I will read more about virtual host. Thank you very much.